# Hypothesis testing in the presence of independent variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

This is something that keeps surfacing in the context of hypothesis testing when using stats in professional settings. Let's say there is some metric we want to measure for two groups of machines. For example, the latency of some operation they perform. I want to be alerted when the latency of the second group is significantly higher than the first one. So, I plug the latency measurements into a two sample t-test. So far so good.

Now, there are a bunch of variables that impact this latency. For example: the type of machine, some configurations within the machine, etc. Let's say we have four or five such variables. The people who manage these machines insist that since these variables impact the latency, we perform the hypothesis test separately across the combinations of theses variables. For example, do one test when machine type is HP, OS running is Linux, concurrency configured is 32, accelerated networking is enabled. And do separate tests for all possible combinations of these four properties. The problem is that once the data is sliced to this extent, it gets spread really thin. For each bucket, we end up with just 3-4 machines in both groups. So, the statistical test doesn't show significant regressions for any of these buckets mainly due to low volume.

One way to address this is to explicitly ensure that all these properties have a similar distribution across the two groups. Then, we can still compare the overall mean. Another can be to do the test one property at a time instead of splitting by all properties at once.

My question is two-fold:

1. What are some ways to address this in the theory of hypothesis testing.
2. How to explain this to the people who manage these machines. They are not experts in Statistics.

Comment: that's what ancova is for. or more generally multiple regression.

Comment: It seems that you have data arriving continuosly, so look into [tag:control-chart]! and more generally, visualization. And use regression